# Year alignment in \cvhonor

Tags: cv, awesome-cv

I'm using a derivation of the `awesome-cv` template to create a CV.

When using `\cvhonor`. the template shows something like this:

[image]

However, I currently have a situation where I got the same award over multiple years, and therefore, in the interests of brevity, I want a single line for each award, even if it was awarded over multiple years.

[image].

Also there is a comma after the year, which is annoying. As I'm using a template, it is quite difficult for me to produce a MWE, so I've tried to extract what I think are the relevant aspects from `.cls` file.

```
% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{%
\vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{%
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
\honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} &    \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}
```

And here is my current code for the awards:

```
\cvsection{Awards}

\begin{cvhonors}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {UCT Masters Research Scholarship}
    {}
    {2013 -- 2014}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {Commerce Faculty Merit Scholarship}
    {}
    {2010 -- 2012}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {Dean's Merit List}
    {}
    {2009 -- 2012}

\end{cvhonors}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as usual on this page you should add an mwe like the following in your questions ... That makes it much more easier to help you!

In your case you can **redefine** the used environment `cvhonors` and command `\cvhonor` like

```
\renewenvironment{cvhonors}{%
\vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.7cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}} % <===========
}{%
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
}

% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\renewcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
\honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1} \honortitlestyle{#2} &    \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}
```

Please see that I used a bigger value for `C{1.7cm}` to get more space for your date to get no linebreak in it and that I deleted the comma in command `\cvhonor`.  Please see that this changings do also change the layout of a section `honors` (if you have one in your code). If you only want to change the layout for your awards, define your own environment `mycvhonors` or `myawards` and command `\mychhonor` or `myaward` ...

Please see the following complete mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

\geometry{%
  showframe,
  left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm
} % Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}


\renewenvironment{cvhonors}{%
\vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.7cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}} % <===========
}{%
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
}

% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\renewcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
\honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1} \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
} 


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~--~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

\cvsection{Education}

\begin{cventries}

\cventry 
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\end{cventries}

\cvsection{Awards}

\begin{cvhonors}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {UCT Masters Research Scholarship}
    {}
    {2013 -- 2014}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {Commerce Faculty Merit Scholarship}
    {}
    {2010 -- 2012}
  \cvhonor
    {}
    {Dean's Merit List}
    {}
    {2009 -- 2012}

\end{cvhonors}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting cv]